# Why am I getting this error? too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django, frame, blogs, trace

I'm creating a blog of stocks and in the views.py I defined the stocks that are in the database, but I don't understand what this error means, so I need a little help with this, thanks in advance! Here are the relevant code parts so you can see what's going on here.

Traceback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\Desktop\basura\lapagina\app1\views.py", line 62, in StockView
    stock_sym = StockNames.objects.get(StockNames.objects.all())
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1247, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

views.py

```py
def StockView(request, sym):
    stock_sym = StockNames.objects.get(StockNames.objects.all())
    stock_posts = Post.objects.filter(stock__symbol=sym)
    
    
    return render(request, 'app1/stockview.html', {'stocks':stock_posts, 'sym':sym, 'stock_sym':stock_sym})
```

urls.py (the last urlpattern)

```py
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views
from .views import PostView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView, LikeView, MyPostsView, AddCommentView, UpdateCommentView, DeleteCommentView

app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/', PostView.as_view(), name = 'Post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name = 'article-detail'),
    path('add_post/',AddPostView.as_view(), name='addpost'),
    path('update_post/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name = 'updatepost'),
    path('delete_post/<int:pk>', DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'deletepost'),
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name = 'add_category'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', views.CategoryView, name = 'category'),
    path('category-list/', views.CategoryListView, name ='category-list'),
    path('like/<int:pk>/', views.LikeView, name = 'like_post'),
    path('my_posts/', views.MyPostsView.as_view(), name = 'my_posts'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/add_comment/', AddCommentView.as_view(), name = 'add_comment'),
    path('update_comment/<int:pk>', UpdateCommentView.as_view(), name = 'updatecomment'),
    path('delete_comment/<int:pk>', DeleteCommentView.as_view(), name = 'deletecomment'),
    path('stock/<str:sym>/', views.StockView, name = 'stock'),
]
```

models.py

```py
class StockNames(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol

        
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'blog_posts')
    stock = models.ForeignKey(StockNames, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual link that is causing the error? Example `localhost:8000/path/to/link`

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/stock/aapl/

Comment: Please clear out this line first ```stock_sym = StockNames.objects.get(StockNames.objects.all())```

Answer (score 0):

the `get` method in `StockNames.objects.get` is supposed to return one row and the correct argument for it is like `StockNames.objects.get(pk=1)`
if you need all stock symbols (without any filter or sorting) you can go with :

```
    stock_sym = StockNames.objects.all()
```